# Build breadcrumbs with custom names

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I'm trying to make my own breadcrumbs service for a web app I'm coding. The only issue is that I want to have custom names for the breadcrumbs, as in their names are not going to be in the path. One idea I have is to replace all `<a ng-href="/home">` with `<a ng-click="goTo('/home', 'Home')">`, for example.

One thing I'm afraid of is the back button for the browser though. It screws things up, I am trying to think of a possible solution with a listener for a $routeChangeSuccess. My service currently looks like this (it's a bit of a mess):

```
portalServices.factory('breadcrumbsService', ['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {

var breadcrumbs = [];

var update = function(name, path) {

    $location.path(path);

    for (var index = 0; index < breadcrumbs.length; index++) {
        if (breadcrumbs[index].path == path) {
            breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs.splice(index + 1);
            break;
        };
    };

    breadcrumbs.push({name: name, path: path});
};


return breadcrumbs;
```

I'm planning to have any controller that has buttons that allow for a change of route to implement the service and to have ng-clicks to do the routing instead of hrefs. I'm also open to suggestions for better solutions.

Edit: fixed a newbie mistake :P

Answer (score 2):

Your Function not works because you defined `var index=0` in for loop. but you wrongly iterate with i in all places instead of index. your code should be

```
for (var i = 0; i < breadcrumbs.length; i++) {
        if (breadcrumbs[index].path == path) {
            breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs.splice(index + 1);
            break;
        };
    };
```

Comment: But what happens when I undo in the browser, @soosmca?

Comment: Replace all index to i

Comment: Got any ideas for how to make the back and forward functionality on the browser update the breadcrumbs properly? @soosmca

Comment: I'd love to accept it if it answered the main problem